# Writing recursive function to identify even/odd

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am working an assignment for Eloquent JavaScript asking you to write a recursive rule to test for 'evenness' of a number. I am always getting false as a return. Please someone help identify my error.

```
function isEven(num){
    if(num===0){
        return(true);
    }else if (num === 1){
        return(false);
    }else {
        num = num - 2;
        return(find(num));
    }
    }


};

console.log(isEven(12));
```

Comment: Is this exactly the code you have? I suspect it does not actually run on account of the extra closing brace.

Comment: You're calling `find` where you should be calling `isEven`.

Comment: OMG that was the name of the first function I wrote and it must be the problem. Ok where 'find' is should be 'isEven' then everything is fine. Thanks! Sorry for such a stupid mistake

Comment: [+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238487/writing-recursive-function-to-identify-even-odd#comment48578454_30238487)1 to counter down-vote, the close button is there for questions that were honest mistakes.

Comment: I am very new here still. How do I close? I tried to accept an answer. @MattiVirkkunen

Comment: @AustinHansen: It's called closing when other people close the question, but you can also delete it yourself if you want to.

Comment: I accepted an answer. Someone may learn from this mistake if they make it themselves also. Thanks everyone.

Comment: But is this calling the function recursively? and you should fix the typos in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of recursion if to call the function within itself. You are really close, but you call find in your function rather than isEven(num - 2)

```
function isEven(num){
    if(num===0){
        return(true);
    }else if (num === 1){
        return(false);
    }else {
        return(isEven(num - 2));
    }
}

console.log(isEven(12));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function isEven(n) {
    if (n === 0) return true;
    if (n === 1) return false;

    return isEven(n - 2);
}
```

However, it's very inefficient. Better to use something like this (e.g. in a real code):

```
function isEven(n) {
    return n % 2 === 0;
}
```

Comment: but you are not calling the function recursively

Answer (score 0):

```
following will solve your problem

    <html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function isOdd(x) {
    return !isEven(x);    
}

function isEven(x) {
    if(x===0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return isOdd(x-1);
    }
}

alert(isOdd(6));

</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```